# Symfony2 functional testing InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I get "InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty." running functional tests through PHPUnit. Here is test i wrote:

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $client = static::createClientWithAuthentication('main');

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'en/manage');

    $send_button = $crawler->selectButton('submit');

    $form = $send_button->form(array(
        'PrCompany[email]' => 'test@example.ua',
        'PrCompany[first_name]' => 'Anton',
        'PrCompany[last_name]' => 'Tverdiuh',
        'PrCompany[timezone]' => 'Europe/Amsterdam'
    ));

    $form['PrCompany[companies][1]']->tick();

    $client->submit($form);


    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("User is invited")')->count() > 0);

}
```

Comment: I think I have a similar question which may help you understand your issue more. No answers yet... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662697/symfony2-functional-testing-crawler-not-working

Comment: You have not marked any question as the answer, so I will add my own, hopefully solving yor question

Comment: I think you need to use `$form['PrCompany[companies]'][1]->tick();
` (with the [1] outside of the quotes)

Comment: Hi @vitalyp ! Did you found answer to this question? I'm struggling with the same problem. Looks like #goutte dont like form input element with array name "name[]".

Answer (score 13):

You can debug the problem by using `var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());`

Additionally, I think you should write this:

```
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

Otherwise you'll be testing the response of the first url, before form submission.

Answer (score 9):

I was also struggling with this, and It appeared that the `selectButton` method  triggered this error.

After reading up on the [DOM Crawler docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/components/dom_crawler.html#forms) I found that the `selectButton` method takes the actual button text as a string argument. So if your button is 'submit my form please', that will be your text.

It does take different parameters too, as shown below (taken from the docs)

```
A selectButton() method is available on the Crawler which returns another 
Crawler that matches a button (input[type=submit], input[type=image], 
or a button) with the given text.
```

**EDIT**

After finally successfully completing the test I would also recommend you follow this example for testing forms:

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://github.com/login');

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Log in')->form();
$form['login'] = 'symfonyfan';
$form['password'] = 'anypass';

$crawler = $client->submit($form);
$this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Welcome Back")')->count() > 0);
```

**The main difference being, I have used the Goutte bundle**, which I installed with composer from [the packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/fabpot/goutte) (in my case I added `"fabpot/goutte": "1.0.*@dev"`)

Comment: I think the whole idea of using the built-in testing is to not need additional libraries. Introducing Goutte seems like overkill when you can do it with the built-in tools

Comment: @Andrew Atkinson is Goutte needed for testing forms? I always get a 'unreachable field' error, when following the standard tutorials

Comment: @skoop In my case I am using Goutte, and works fine.

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson `selectButton()` seems to accept *Exact* name of button's `value`. How to get form if button name is not given?

Comment: @Volatil3 Maybe you can enter each input separately with their xpath or css path? - Just a guess

Comment: @Volatil3 I agree, you could.

Comment: @skoop I totally agree now

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to what @greg0ire wrote, check to see if

```
var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

Returns a redirect page instead of the actual content.  If so, you can add this:

```
$client->followRedirects(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Silex application. I was looking for

```
$buttonCrawler = $crawler->selectButton('input[type="submit"]');
```

Instead, the correct way to do it is give the **value** of the button

```
$buttonCrawler = $crawler->selectButton('value_of_the_button');
```

For example, in your page:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

And in your tests:

```
$buttonCrawler = $crawler->selectButton('Click Me');
$form = $buttonCrawler->form();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I see question still dont have answer. I had the same problem.

In my case goutte was not able to do this request because input name is changed by javascript on the fly.

When goutte received html it saw one form. And when submitting with pre filled params, form input elements could not be matched by `$form->setValues($params)` so \InvalidArgumentException was thrown.

Solved by doing request by hand.

```
// $form->setValues($data);
// $this->getGoutte()->submit($form);

$data = array(
    'input_name[key]' => 'value'
);
$this->getGoutte()->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Codeception](http://codeception.com/01-20-2012/starting-acceptance.html) with Symfony2 module. It provides flexible interface to Symfony2 functional tests and has better debugging features.

Answer (score 0):

This error would occur when crawler can't find form element requested; Quite tricky when you are using, for instance, form builder as when run, it will create different input name:

```
$form = $this-> createFormBuilder($store)
           ->add('storeNumber','text')
           ->add('storeName','text')
           ->add('save', 'submit')
           ->getForm();
```

will output field name like:

```
form_storeNumber
```

which should be used in test class:

```
$form=$crawler->selectButton('save')->form();
$form['form_storeNumber']='10';
```