# PHPUnit The current node list is empty

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I am creating some functional tests to test my controller. I have 2 functions at the moment. 1 for loggin in and 1 for the entity life cycle.

both should run normally (I guess). Yet I am getting the following error:

> The current node list is empty

I tried removing all my code from the test class with no result. I also tried adding an empty method to see if it also happens there. And yes it does. That test also crashes.

So I googled for a solution. I tried a few things, like:

([$client = static::createClient(array(), array('HTTP_HOST' => 'symfony.dev'));](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662697/symfony2-functional-testing-crawler-not-working))

[var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469802/symfony2-functional-testing-invalidargumentexception-the-current-node-list-is-e) (which gets the page where the test should be)

[Change the header](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1282):

```
$response = $this->render('CMSBundle:Front:test.html.twig',);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');       

return $response;
```

And some other things. None of them worked. I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is.

Does anyone has any suggestions on this problem?

My test code:

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $client = $this->client;

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/login');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET /admin/login");

    // Fill in the form and submit it
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Inloggen')->form(array(
        '_username'  => 'erik',
        '_password'  => 'erik'
    ));
    $client->submit($form);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching I found the answer here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662697/symfony2-functional-testing-crawler-not-working?lq=1).

The symfony2 crawler, by default, guesses that the location of server is at "localhost". Yet mine is not there. So I had to tell the crawler where to look.

This is the code I had to add `'HTTP_HOST' => 'my.server.location'`

Adding this code makes the code look like this:

```
$this->client = static::createClient( 
     array(),
     array(
        'HTTP_HOST' => 'my.server.location', //dependent on server        
    ));
$this->client->followRedirects(true);
```

So now when I get the url `$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/login');`, The crawler will get the following url: `http://my.server.location/admin/login`.

Hope this helps anyone!

*And credits to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308375/matt) for the answer*