# InvalidArgumentException in Crawler.php line 516: The current node list is empty. with laravel-goutte

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, laravel-5, goutte

why when I execute the code in the document of the laravel-goutte it doesn't work , that code is in the main page of the package on github:

https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte

```
use Weidner\Goutte\GoutteFacadeGoutte;


Route::get('/', function() {
    $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'http://duckduckgo.com/?q=Laravel');
    $url = $crawler->filter('.result__title > a')->first()->attr('href');
    dump($url);
    return view('welcome');
});
```

and shows that error

[image: error message]

I use laravel 2.2.29

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328653/phpu%20nit-the-current-node-list-is-empty

Answer (score 2):

Your `filter`did not return any results. That is why it crashed. That's how I solved this issue, by adding a try catch.

```
try {
   $url = $crawler->filter('.result__title > a')->first()->attr('href');
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // Handle the current node list is empty..
}
```