# Error trying to select a form from symfony2 crawler?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, symfony, phpunit

I keep getting the following error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Caremonk\MainSiteBundle\Tests\Controller\SecurityControllerFunctionalTest::testIndex
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
```

But when I navigate to the localhost/login, my form populates with the correct content. The line that says...

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('login')->form();
```

is causing the error. What is wrong with my test?

Functional Test:

```
<?php

namespace Caremonk\MainSiteBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class SecurityControllerFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('login')->form();
        $form['username'] = 'testActive';
        $form['password'] = 'passwordActive';
    }
}
```

Twig view:

```
{# src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig #}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('caremonk_mainsite_login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Started doing functional testing in symfony2 and found your question unanswered, so here we go,

selectButton method takes the actual button text as a string argument. So if your button is 'submit my form please', that will be your text.

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit my form please')->form();
```

Checkout the answer by Andrew [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469802/symfony2-functional-testing-invalidargumentexception-the-current-node-list-is-e)

Comment: The parameters also require the underscore prepended, e.g. ```_username```

Answer (score 19):

Answer of Vineet is right but... in my opinion is not good idea to take form from button.
Better try:

```
$crawler->filter('form[name=yourAwesomeFormName]')->form();
```

or change name for class,id etc. On one view can be more then 1 form with identic submit value

Comment: amazing thanks, was wondering if there was a way of getting the form other than from the button!

Comment: Definitely the best option since the text might change and not be reflected on dev side (dependent on translations, wording changed by client request...)

Comment: I agree, selecting a form by a label feels uncertain and might easily break. A tip here is to use a constant for the form id that you can use in all your tests. If it changes, you only have to change the constant.

Answer (score 0):

`selectButton()` selects a button by `name` or `alt` value for images.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is why I had this error and how I solved it.

(Using [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte))
The crawler is acting like a browser with GET.

So, when doing:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
```

The crawler is trying to reach `http://localhost/login`

So, basically, I changed it to:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://site.dev/app_dev.php/login');
```

**site.dev** being my virtual host for my symfony project.

Hope it helps!