# Symfony2 functional testing error with selectButton function

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I get an "InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty." error with my functional tests on Symfony2.

According to [different posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469802/symfony2-functional-testing-invalidargumentexception-the-current-node-list-is-e/29010097#29010097) I have wrote the following code:

In the Test Class:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/site/web/app_dev.php/en/offer');
$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('SUBMIT');
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
$form['travelComment'] = 'Hey there!';
```

In the twig:

```
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input value="SUBMIT" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />     
</form>
```

As you can see the input value SUBMIT is the same in the selectbutton function.

Then I get the following message:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
```

Comment: Please add the rendered HTML code, by looking at the source of the page from your computer. Look closely at the question you linked: did you forgot the name of the form e.g. `form[travelComment]`?

Comment: try adding `name="SUBMIT"`

Comment: Have you solved? Try investigating on the structure of the generated html: if your html is not valid, i.e. an unclused tag, the crawler don't work as expecected. Hope this help

Comment: Thks for your help. I have tried with name="SUBMIT" with no result. I still have the same message. The rendered HTML code seems to be good : `<input name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">`. I will look for an unclosed tag.